# configuring only subdomain on apache2

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, subdomain

I have a domain and subdomains on a server say example.com and api.example.com
We want to add another server to our application cdn.example.com which is a different physical server. So i'm trying to configure subdomain cdn.example.com
I've mapped the ip of new server to subdomain cdn.example.com

when i ping cdn.example.com its returning correct ip. But when i put this url in browsers its now showing page in the subdomain directory.

I've create virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cdn.example.com

when i try to open site using ip its showing the pages in default directory /var/www/index.html

i;ve mapped the cdn.example.com to folder /srv/www/cdn.example.com/public_html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     ServerName cdn.example.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/cdn.example.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/cdn.example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/cdn.example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

this is my cdn.example.com file in sites-enabled directory

I have two questions:
1. is it necessary to configure main domain before configuring subdomain?
2. can we configure only subdomain on server?

PS: I have debian 6.0.3 on my new server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. is it necessary to configure main domain before configuring subdomain?

No.

A useful point is that the first defined site is the one that is served if the client request is for a site domain name or address not in the Apache configuration explicitly.

> 2. can we configure only subdomain on server?

Yes.

You'll need to arrange in DNS that the subdomain's address records point to the appropriate web-server.